# The set up of the school in "Soredemo Ayumu wa Yosetekuru"?

Tags: when-will-ayumu-make-his-move

I was reading the seventy-seventh chapter of *Soredemo Ayumu wa Yosetekuru*, and Kagawa Rin figures out that Ayumu likes Urushi, she heads off to confirm it. She finds Kakuryuu and aks him. He responds by saying:

> "... I don't know who you heard that from, But it's pretty surprising for Ayumu, right?"

Following this photo:

[image: photo]

When he responds to Rin's question he is sitting at a student's desk but next to a window that looks into the hall. The question I'm asking is how is he leaning out of the window. Is this just how schools are designed in Japan or is this just a thing the Author did to be convenient. Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but that is how most class rooms are in Japan (in public school buildings at least).

Typically, classrooms are aligned next to each other along a long corridor (廊下, which you called a hall). Kakuryuu is inside his classroom, looking out to the corridor.

For example, the following is from [here](http://www.yokote-seiryou.net/img/fukan/hukanzu.pdf); the grayed area is corridor; 高校2年普通教室2-x are classrooms (for the second year high school students). You can get real pictures by [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E6%95%99%E5%AE%A4%20%E5%BB%8A%E4%B8%8B).

[image: plane]